# Query seems executing despite it is finished in Impala

Tags: hive, impala

I am running a query and despite the fact that it reached the limit in (8 mins) and it seems `FINISHED` inside the query details in CM, it stops at (19 mins). Why is this happening? I saw the below information in query details:

```
First row fetched: 7.9m (75ms)
Last row fetched: 8.0m (7.21s)
Released admission control resources: 19.5m (11.6m)
Unregister query: 19.5m (103ms)
```